# RexExp find a word within a list of words that are within a parenthesis

Tags: regex

Good morning,

I am writing to you because I am getting stuck with RegExp.

I have to read a list of attributes from a string like this

"@RESULTS({34500}attribute1/attribute2/attribute3) blabla @RESULTS({36500}attribute4/attribute2/attribute5) blabla @RESULTS({38500}attribute6/attribute7/attribute8)

This gives the names of the attributes matching values 34500, 36500 and 38500.

I am being returned this list and I want to parse if attribute2 is present in the list

So I want my regexp to return @RESULTS({34500}attribute1/attribute2/attribute3) and @RESULTS({36500}attribute4/attribute2/attribute5)

At the moment I am using @RESULTS\(.*?\) which returns the 3 results, but I can't figure out how to get only the ones with attribute2.
I have been struggling for long.

Any help is very welcome.

Many thanks

Gilles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `@RESULTS\(.*/attribute2/.*\)`

Comment: Yes, what about it? Why do you think it should help? Please explain it in your answer.

Comment: It was almost this. What works is: @RESULTS\(.*\/attribute2\/.*?\). Thank you very much. I had tried without the / and this did not work. Thank you again

Comment: May I ask you another question. What if attribute name is like product.type? And I want to search product.type?

Comment: @Gilles: For product.type your regex should be like @RESULTS(.*\/product\.type\/.*?)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Mate, this must do the work

```
@RESULTS\(.*attribute2.*\)
```

But depending on the language you are using it will require different scape character (\ in this case)

I always test my regexes at http://www.regexplanet.com/ before going to the code

Cheers